# Non-deprecated way of outputting string containing entity (reserved character) Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, entity, symbols, decoding

I have looked a lot around stack but the terminology confuses the search engine. Having a string like this:

```js
const aux = 'MyCar&reg; ensures you that it does not store personal data.
```

how would I be able to display the html-specially encoded symbol ("entity" according to MDN) `&reg;` as `®` in my website?

Do I really need to use regular expressions (regex) like below?

```js
aux.replace(/&reg;/g, "®")
```

output:

```
MyCar&reg; ensures you that it does not store personal data.
```

I have seen some threads where `escape` is mentioned. Which one is the most up-to-date option to go about this?

Comment: Did you try `&#174;`? - The browser should translate that into the symbol. For that matter it should translate `&reg` too, without you needing to do any replacement.

Comment: @MichaelHorn thank you for the suggestion! I tried but it doesn't work.